# Bottom navigation view with custom item (actionLayout)

Tags: android, android-view, android-menu

I would like to add a custom item in the new [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) .

There are plenty of tutorial of adding a custom view with the normal navigation view but I can't find anything regarding the bottom one.

This is my view

```
   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

And this is the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_one"
    android:title="one" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_two"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/item_action_notification"
    android:title="two" />
```

As you can see I put **actionLayout** tag as you would do normally, but it is simply not displayed.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Manza, Did you find the solution to this problem ? I am running into same situation. I tried using action layout and action view class, nothing get displays.

Comment: @aNoviceGuy Unfortunalet not yey :(

Comment: Do you know how to add divider in between of them ?>

Comment: @AnshulTyagi, wrapping in a [`<group>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#groups) will make a separator appear between menu items.

Comment: @Manza did you find a solution for this yet ?

Comment: Not really, still haven't tried Pramila's solution though

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Hope the below solution will help.

1. Create a layout : **layout/_custom_cart_item_layout.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
   android:layout_width="20dp"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:background="@drawable/circle"
   android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="0"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:textSize="12sp" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. **drawable/circle**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
   <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp" />
   </shape>
   ```
3. MainActivity : **layout/main_activity.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.MainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   android:id="@+id/bot_nav"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="56dp"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:elevation="2dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
4. menu : **menu/bottom_menu.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item
   android:id="@+id/menu_home"
   android:icon="@drawable/home24"
   android:title="Home" />

   <item
   android:id="@+id/menu_cart"
   android:icon="@drawable/shoppingcart24"
   android:title="Cart" />
   <item
   android:id="@+id/menu_acct"
   android:icon="@drawable/user24"
   android:title="Account" />
   </menu>
   ```
5. In your MainActivity class within **onCreate**

   ```
   BottomNavigationView mbottomNavigationView =findViewById(R.id.bot_nav);

   BottomNavigationMenuView mbottomNavigationMenuView =
   (BottomNavigationMenuView) mbottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

   View view = mbottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(1);

   BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) view;

   View cart_badge = LayoutInflater.from(this)
   .inflate(R.layout._custom_cart_item_layout,
    mbottomNavigationMenuView, false);

   itemView.addView(cart_badge);
   ```

[Output : Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XS1o.jpg)

Hope it will work similar for you.

Thank you

Comment: i am so sorry i voted down your answer by mistake , this is working just fine

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat No prob regarding votes , You got it right , Thanks :)

Comment: Working perfect, thanks for giving proper solution @PramilaShankar

Comment: Thank you @Sachin

Comment: Able to add badge but facing issues when switching betweens menuItems.
When menuItem is selected label scalesUp and menu icon shiftsUp but badge doesn't shiftUp leading to misplaced badge.
Any suggestions @PramilaShankar

Comment: the newly added view is not desplaying in the center, it is not taking the exact position of the tab for which it is added.

Comment: This worked perfectly with my current app theme  - Appcompat theme. Other solutions required material theme